# Inputting password

Tags: windows, passwords, login, login-screen, password-protection

I have recently signed in to Windows 10.There after,I am asked to enter password everytime I open my computer.

Is there any way to disable this feature?
Does this feature need working Internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this feature need working Internet connection?

I think it only should need an established connection unless you are using a local user/pass to login instead of your email user/pass account.

> Is there any way to disable this feature?

Yes, an automatic logon could be set in Windows.

### Steps

1. First step is to open Run command box by simultaneously pressing Windows logo and R keys (Windows+R). In the Run dialog box, type Netplwiz and then press Enter key.

[image]

2. In the resulting User Accounts dialog, select your user account first and then uncheck the option labelled Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer. Click Apply button to see Automatically sign in box.

[image]

[image]

3. In the Automatically sign in dialog, type your password and then re-enter the password to confirm the same.

[image]

Finally, click OK button.

---

Sources and tutorial for other methodologies:

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-automatically-login-in-windows-10/

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/turn-on-automatic-logon